# Is there a way to prevent javascript from adding "smooth" scrolling to a page?

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling

Smooth scrolling has always felt very slow and laggy for me (i want everything snappy), but thankfully it has been possible to disable in the browser settings. However, i am noticing that more and more web pages are using javascript to force smooth scrolling regardless of my settings (such as [this page](http://toughviking.se/) and [this demo](https://fatlinesofcode.github.io/jquery.smoothwheel/demo/smoothwheel.html)), utterly breaking my browsing experience.

So my question is this: Is there any way to prevent pages from using javascript to force smooth scrolling? Perhaps in the form of a chrome extension or a userscript?

Comment: Possibly related? http://superuser.com/questions/615266/how-to-disable-smooth-scrolling-on-the-winrt-side

Comment: E-mail the folks at the site, tell them what a usability joke their forced scrolling mechanisms are.  These sorts of additions to sites are rarely grounded in utility and are meant to impress the folks that probably paid for the site.

Comment: Smashing Magazine agrees with OP as they devote a paragraph to why smooth scrolling is a bad idea: See: [Usability Do’s And Don’ts For Interactive Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/27/usability-dos-and-donts-for-interactive-design/) So the best answer is probably Brad's comment.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking, I thought maybe a smooth scrolling extension would do the trick, and ironically it does.

I am using the "SmoothScoll" extension for Chrome. By going into it's options and changing the setting "Animation time [ms]" to 0, it can force web pages that would otherwise try to force smooth scrolling on me to scroll instantly.

I don't know many forced smooth scrolling websites off the top of my head though, so I only tried it on one site that I remember doing that to me yesterday. Feedback on whether or not this works on other sites for other people would be appreciated.

[edit]
I tested it on the examples in the original post and it doesn't seem to work there. It should hopefully work in most cases though.

Comment: The reason SmoothScroll (and possibly other extensions) doesn't work for "[this demo](https://fatlinesofcode.github.io/jquery.smoothwheel/demo/smoothwheel.html)" is because the extension is probably attaching an event listener to the window or document and blocking that way, while the example only attaches to a "DIV" element, not sure if there's any good way to solve this that doesn't involve adding an event listener to every scrollable element.